# Adding Font in iReport

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to use Garamond font for my PDF report, i'm using iReport in Mac.

I have downloaded font from

[Garamond-Regular](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Garamond+Regular/)

Added this font in iReport using iReport->Preferences->Fonts->Install Font

During installation i have selected "Embed this font in the PDF document" and encoding format to default.

I have exported the ttf to jar "Garamond-Regular.jar" and added to classpath, While viewing the report it shows "Error displaying the report page. See console for details", but in console there are no errors.

[image]
[image]

How can i add/generate report with the font? Help me.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't added the ttf file of the font in the jre/lib/fonts in your JAVA_HOME. You will most probably have to restart iReport as well. :)